# WiX: How to schedule the InstallUISequence

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I am working on a installer. It is very simple; I just to write some key into the [Windows Registry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry). But before doing this, I have to check some conditions, so I make four dialogs:

1. Welcome;
2. Check that connection to the Internet is available
3. Check that the database is accessible
4. Write the registry and show finish information.

And I schedule the InstallUISequence like below.

```
<InstallUISequence>
    <Show Dialog="Welcome"
          After="ExecuteAction"/>
</InstallUISequence>
```

And I use the "next" and "pre" to navigate the other dialogs. It works, but the welcome dialog do not show immediately. Half a minute after the prepare dialog and during this half a minute, it has no progress dialog - it seems the install has finished.

In view of this, I change the schedule like this in the Welcome dialog:

```
<InstallUISequence>
    <Show Dialog="Welcome"
          before="ExecuteAction"/>
 </InstallUISequence>
```

And in the writeRegistry dialog:

```
<InstallUISequence>
    <Show Dialog="writeRegistry"
          After="ExecuteAction"/>
</InstallUISequence>
```

I want to do the ExecuteAction (write the registry) before showing the dialog writeRegistry. But it seems that there is nothing has been written into the registry.

What is the problem here and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score -1):

[ExecuteAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368565%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) handles InstallExecuteSequence. So when this action starts, the installation is performed.

All your dialogs should be scheduled **before** ExecuteAction.

Comment: thanks for your response,Cosmin Pirvu

I had tried what you said,but it seems do not work like what i want.

after all the dialog finished,there is nothing has been wrote into the registry.

Comment: That's a different problem. Did you investigate why it no registry entries are created? Did you configure your registry elements correctly? http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/write_a_registry_entry.htm

Comment: I think i have done it correctly,because if i schedule the dialog after
ExecuteAction, It will write the right thing into registry.thanks again!

Comment: How is the dialog connected to your registry entries?

Comment: <Component Id="x86RegistryEntriesHKCU" Guid="D136B643-72D9-4477-AEAE-D4C4DF48017C" Win64="no">
in Directory node and
<ComponentRef Id="x86RegistryEntriesHKLM"/> in Feature node

Comment: There may be various post-processing necessary steps that happen after a performed installation? Storing serial keys etc. Calling Custom Actions etc.